# SQL query to create rows for missing range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Thats probably not the best description of the question but here we go.

So I have some data that looks something like this, notice that for the Schoolhouse project Tom only has entries for 12/4 & 12/8 while for the pool project he has an entry through the 25th.

```
Consultant   Project       PM    Week        Hours
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/4/2016     4
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/11/2016    6
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/4/2016     9
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/11/2016    8
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/18/2016    12
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/25/2016    3
```

I am looking for a query where I can output rows through the entire range for both\all projects. So ideally the result would look something like this

```
Consultant   Project       PM    Week        Hours
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/4/2016     4
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/11/2016    6
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/18/2016    0
Tom          Schoolhouse  Sue    12/25/2016    0
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/4/2016     9
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/11/2016    8
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/18/2016    12
Tom          Pool         Joe    12/25/2016    3
```

Now here is the kicker... I am writing this query in a system where I have limited SQL capabilities. I cannot use functions or cursors or variables. I can only write a basic SQL statement. I did try to figure something out where I populated a table with the ranges that I need and then joined to this table but it isn't working like I would expect.

Comment: Please tell us the db

Comment: Sorry using MS SQlL 2008

Comment: Add the tag please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charles's idea is on the right track, but you need to include the right columns and select from the correct tables:

```
select t.Consultant, t.Project, t.PM, w.Week,
       coalesce(t.Hours, 0) as hours
From (Select distinct Consultant, Project, PM from t) cpp cross join
     (Select distinct week from t) w left join
     t 
     on t.consultant = cpp.consultant and .project = cpp.Project and
        t.PM = cpp.PM and t.week = w.week;
```

Comment: still getting nulls

Comment: OK I got it, had to reference cpp for the null columns. So far it looks like its working awesome. Thanks so much. I currently have a ton of Javascript doing this and it's a nightmare to debug. Now that I have "clean" data it'll be much easier. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select d.Consultant, p.Project, 
     d.PM, w.Week, isnull(d.Hours, 0) hours
From 
    (Select distinct project from mytable) p
      cross join
    (Select distinct week from myTable) w
  left join mytable d
      on d.project = p.Project
         and d.week = w.week
```

if consultant and pm are dependent on Project, then:

```
select p.Consultant, p.Project, 
     p.PM, w.Week, isnull(d.Hours, 0) hours
From 
    (Select distinct Consultant, project, PM from mytable) p
      cross join
    (Select distinct week from myTable) w
  left join mytable d
      on d.project = p.Project
         and d.week = w.week
```

Comment: use `w.week` and `p.project` in the query.

Comment: I made a fiddle for this but it's not returning what I would expect    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/312a47/1     I know, it's mysql in the fiddle...

Comment: vkp, that is getting close but the Consultant & PM are null in some rows

Comment: just tested and noticed that, but still getting nulls for `consultant` and `PM`. to fix, need to know whether `Consultant` and `PM` are dependent on `Project`, or are independent attributes. If independent, (i.e., multiple rows with same `project` can have different values for `Consultant` and `PM`),  then I suspect desired query is not possible.